# Check if class is added to element or not

Tags: javascript

I have coded to verify that the class in `p` is added or not using javascript.

```js
function ll_ctq() {

  var check_ll_ctq = document.getElementById("ll_ctq"),
    classes = ['red_cross'];

  if (check_ll_ctq == "red_cross") {
    alert("Yes");
  } else {
    alert("No");
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="ll_ctq()">
  <p id="ll_ctq" class="red_cross">Hello</p>
</body>
```

But it always alerts **`No`**.

Comment: looking for properties `className` or `classList` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** to get the list of classes of the `check_ll_ctq` element, then call `.contains` to check if the list contain the class `red_cross`, like :

```
if ( check_ll_ctq.classList.contains("red_cross") ) {
    alert("Yes");
} else {
    alert("No");
}
```

```js
function ll_ctq() {
  var check_ll_ctq = document.getElementById("ll_ctq"),
    classes = ['red_cross'];

  if (check_ll_ctq.classList.contains("red_cross")) {
    alert("Yes");
  } else {
    alert("No");
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="ll_ctq()">
  <p id="ll_ctq" class="red_cross">Hello</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the element as a variable:

```
var check_ll_ctq = document.getElementById("ll_ctq");
```

Then check it's className property to see if it is equivalent:

```
if (check_ll_ctq.className === "red_cross") {
    alert("Yes");
  } else {
    alert("No");
  }
```